# Change of Coordinates for Discrete-Time Affine Dynamical System $X_{k+1} = A\,X_{k}\,A^{T} + B$.

Tags: dynamical-systems, coordinate-systems

This question is related, but distinct from, a [question I posted the other day](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3817829/change-of-coordinates-for-discrete-time-affine-dynamical-system-x-k1-a-x). I am looking at an iterative matrix equation
$$X_{k+1} = A\,X_{k}\,A^{T} + B,$$
where $X$, $A$, and $B$ are all $n \times n$ real matrices. I was wondering if there was a "change of coordinates" to transform this equation into one of the form
$$Y_{k+1} = A\,Y_{k}\,A^{T}$$
or something of the sort that was easier to analyze.

My first thought was to try something similar to the change of coordinates one would use for
$$x_{k+1} = A\,x_{k} + b$$
which is
$$x \to x + \left(I - A\right)^{-1}\,b$$
or the change of coordinates one would use for
$$x_{k+1} = x_{k}\,A^T + b$$
which would be
$$x \to x + b\,\left(I - A\right)^{-1}.$$

To this end, I considered the change of coordinates
$$X \to X + C$$
where $C$ is a matrix I will determine later. Using this change of coordinates, the iterative equation becomes
$$X_{k+1} = A\,X_{k}\,A^{T} + A\,C\,A^{T} - C + B.$$
So $C$ would have to satisfy
$$B = C - A\,C\,A^{T}.$$
The difficulty here is that $C$ is being multiplied on the left and right by a matrix, so it isn't apparent to me how to combine the terms on the right.